# Failed to assert identity with UsernameToken when connecting to weblogic web service using wss4j

Tags: java, web-services, weblogic, ws-security, wss4j

I'm trying to connect to a web service using wss4j in order to wrap my xml with a username token security with password in digest form, below is my request output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soapenv:Header>
<wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
<wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-C53A9DE4F384C9293314044748291431">
<wsse:Username>weblogicdev</wsse:Username>
<wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordDigest">cfxACgO/wSzJSIjd9r8119BURWY=</wsse:Password>
<wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">76O2tFwe2NQLw/ZOiTgtyA==</wsse:Nonce>
<wsu:Created>2014-07-04T11:53:49.141Z</wsu:Created>
</wsse:UsernameToken>
</wsse:Security>
</soapenv:Header>
<soapenv:Body>
<mdsl:CustomerRequest xmlns:mdsl="www.mdsl.eft.cms.com">
<mdsl:Institution>1
</mdsl:Institution>
<mdsl:Customer_ID>00236615
</mdsl:Customer_ID>
<mdsl:Data_Level>A
</mdsl:Data_Level>
</mdsl:CustomerRequest>   
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I can't seem to figure out why this request is giving me a:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<env:Body>
<env:Fault xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
<faultcode>wsse:FailedAuthentication</faultcode>
<faultstring>Failed to assert identity with UsernameToken.</faultstring>
</env:Fault>
</env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

But when I implement ws security on jdev with password digest the request works.(jax-ws implementation with weblogic api)

The username weblogicdev and password weblogic123 are valid and the request worked when the policy I put on the web service was a username password token plain (clear text password)

Does oracle process the digest password differently than the one made with wss4j ?
and if it does, does anyone have an algorithm I can use in order to replicate this password digest generation ?

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue? I'm getting the same error. Thanks!

Comment: Hey @BenCarlson, sadly it wasn't worth going beyond this point in my company and we resorted to keeping the username password token plain. However, I came across one forum post saying that oracle does process the digest password differently, but I haven't found enough sources to prove it.
If you came across any sources that could help on this matter it would be great to post your answer for the problem here.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the authentication method you choose for your webservices, you might have to add this user/password to the SecurityRealm in your weblogic admin console.